# text popup on google static map

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, java-me

My requirement is to display a small text popup on the google static map.Say for some locality abc street when user selects the abc street the text popup should appear that displays the some details about the selected place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the [Google Maps Static API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) doesn't support this option, but you can find 3rd party solutions like [this one](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/9/infowindows-with-google-static-maps).

Comment: Thank you Naoise Golden..Is it possible to implement it in blackberry?

Comment: I guess you mean for whatever browser blackberry uses... I dont know, sorry.

Comment: For an application I am developing